# What is the correct way to pass signed integer to smart contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan

I am trying to pass a negative integer to smart contract, but it is not success.

Take this smart contract as an example
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc90ea5fa2d3eacbd63ae9e37c80a5772e57785b6#readContract#F15

When calling ticks function, it requires int24 as an input parameter.

#1. input = -276200

It gives error saying "invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="00000000000000000-276200", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)"

#2. input = 0xFBC918

It gives error saying "value out-of-bounds (argument=null, value="0x000000000000000000FBC918", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)"

What would be the correct input to pass negative number to smart contract function? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use it directly on etherscan i don't know how to help you but in ethers you can do it straight as -276200

```
//...
    const mintingParams = {
      token0: token0,
      token1: token1,
      fee: fee,
      tickLower: -276200,
      tickUpper: 276200,
      amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
      amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
      amount0Min: amount0Min,
      amount1Min: amount1Min,
      recipient: recipient,
      deadline: deadline,
    }
    
    const tx = uniswapV3Pool.mint(mintingParams)

    tx.wait()
    return tx.hash

//...
```

Comment: I consider this as accepted answer. I overlooked the parameter and passed it as string, ie. "-276200", but it gave the error "invalid BigNumber string". However, if I pass it after parseInt, it responses with correct result now.

Comment: Glad i could help you finding the solution :)